# Ignoring specific files in recentf-mode

Tags: files, recentf

I use `company-statistics` to sort completion candidates by previous completion choices. It works perfectly, except there is only tiny problem. The file `~/.emacs.d/company-statistics-cache.el` pops up in `recentf-mode` and I'd like `recentf-mode` to not display this file. How can I achieve this ?

I added the path of the file to the symbol `recentf-exclude` but that did not help. I also tried adding the path of the directory itself and that didn't help either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
(add-to-list 'recentf-exclude "company-statistics-cache.el")
```

or more accurately

```
(add-to-list 'recentf-exclude
             (recentf-expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/company-statistics-cache.el"))
```

then run `M-x recentf-cleanup` to make it work.

Anyway, the regexp you set in `recentf-exclude` must match the `$HOME/.emacs.d/company-statistics-cache.el` (`~` is expanded into `$HOME`), so regexp like `~/.emacs.d/company-statistics-cache.el` does not work.

Comment: Is there any way to ignore empty files as well like `__init__`?

Comment: @alper I think yes since `recentf-exclude` supports both regexp and function.

Comment: I have added `(add-to-list 'recentf-exclude "\\__init__.\\'")` but seems like it still shows up :(

Comment: @alper your regexp is invalid.

Comment: Shouldn't I write the filename in between `\\` ? @xuchunyang

Comment: @alper Use the regexp you can understand, for example, `"__init__"` is probably good enough. See also [(emacs) Regexp Backslash](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Backslash.html)

Comment: Thanks! What would be for `*.py` =>  `*.py    0 Python   ~/*.py`?  That files does not exist and I am not use why it is keep shown on the `recentf`?

Comment: @alper Sorry, I don't understand the question.

Comment: There are files names as `*Find*`, `*.py` may emerge on the recentf list. I want to discard them as well but I am not sure how could I provide `*` as string and `__init__.py` file keep emerges even when i did: `(add-to-list 'recentf-exclude "__init__.py'")`

Comment: @alper Use `"\\*"` to match a literal `*`, e.g., `(string-match "\\*" "*scratch*") ;; 0`. There is an extra apostrophe in your regexp, i.e., it should be `"__init__.py"`.

Comment: Can `recentf-cleanup` run automatically?