# Ignoring specific files in recentf-mode by their exact filenames

Tags: regular-expressions, recentf

I am having trouble to [Ignoring specific files in recentf-mode](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/27141/18414).

> `(add-to-list 'recentf-exclude "company-statistics-cache.el")`

---

On my end, I want to ignore them by their exact file names instead of their file paths.

The filenames I want to ignore are:

- `__init__.py`
- `*Find*`
- `*.py` (This this actually a filename that emergess)
- All files staring with `flycheck_`: `flycheck_*.py`

and if possible any file that has size of 0, which has `Fundamental` mode.

I have come up with following, which does not work, I am not sure where I am doing wrong:

```
(recentf-mode 1)
(setq recentf-exclude '("\\__init__.py\\'"
                        "*Find*'"
                        "\\*.py\\'"
                        "flycheck_*.py\\'"
                        ))
(setq recentf-max-menu-items 25)
(setq recentf-max-saved-items 25)
```

Comment: first pattern doesn't end in quote.

Comment: Fixed it but still does not help

Comment: Updating `recentf-exclude` won't work for files which are already listed. You should either cleanup the list with the new rules `M-x recentf-cleanup` or wait until they're pulled off. Anyway you should double check your regexps, some need more care.

Comment: having only `(setq recentf-exclude '("\\__init__.py\\'")` does not work even, is it normal?

Comment: try `"__init__\\.py\\'"`.  escaping `_` with `\\_` leads to nowhere. Vid. [Regexp-Backslash](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Backslash.html). Be sure that the file is in your recentf list, eval your setq, run `recentf-cleanup` and check again, it should have dissapeared from the list.

Comment: It does not dissapear

Comment: Cannot tell you more, it does excludes the intended files here with that pattern or any other I try either using `recentf-open-files` and/or `counsel-recentf`. Perhaps you're getting something else in the way.

Comment: Shoud I set `recentf-exclude` before enabling `recentf-mode`?

Comment: Paste this [gist](https://gist.github.com/muihlinn/520a10279b9ba620497228bdd758860a) in your scratch buffer, follow directions evaluating line by line (`C-j`), and check results. It does exclude the given pattern.